# How can the "exit" encoding channel in Vega be used?

Tags: visualization, vega-lite, vega

I'm familiar with the enter, update, and exit pattern in d3.js, but I'm struggling to see how one could effectively use the exit channel in Vega. For example, In d3.js you have selection.remove() (https://d3js.org/d3-selection/modifying#selection_remove). You can do things to your "exiting" selections like transitioning opacity to zero, moving marks offscreen, etc. before calling selection.remove() to remove those marks from from the DOM. As far as I know, Vega doesn't have remove(), so I'm struggling to see how the exit channel fits in as I'm assuming that those marks get removed from the DOM immediately in Vega.

I created [this spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/f84ade73e9ca17b6a1fcd1fb8ce66cdd/spec.json) to simulate Mike Bostock's [*selection.join* example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join), but here I'm only using the update channel. Although you can implement easing with timers, I understand that Vega doesn't support animations natively [yet](https://vis.csail.mit.edu/pubs/animated-vega-lite/). So what is Exit in Vega for currently? Was it put in knowing that animations (transitions?) would be added later? I don't think I've ever come across a Vega example that uses it.